# BokkyPooBah reached 2k reputation - who's next?

Tags: discussion, new-users, site-promotion, reputation

#### Congratualtions BokkyPooBah for [reaching 2k reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) in two weeks!

Every healthy beta site needs a [dozen very active users](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/89704/ethereum). BokkyPooBah managed to show us how it's possible to write a lot of high-quality answers in quite a short amount of time.

We still need 2-3 members with 10k+ reputation, around 10 more members with 3k+ reputation and around 50 users with 200+ repuation. (Moderators excluded.)

#### Why is that?

After a site graduates out of Beta state, privileges will be harder to earn.

- 10k reputation allows access to moderator tools (access reports, delete questions, review reviews).
- 3k reputation allows to cast close and reopen votes which is among the most important moderation tools for the community to help deciding which questions are on- or off-topic for the site and help spotting duplicates.
- 200 reputation is generally measured to show the user has understood the mechanics of a stack exchange site.

#### How to gain reputation fast?

[Extracted from Stack Exchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17250/226837):

1. **Post quality answers.** This should be numbered 1 2 and 3. But a good answer will more often than not trump a fast answer. Though there are cases where it does not.
2. **Monitor the [frontpage](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/) and the [new questions list.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest)** Learn their cache time and refresh accordingly or use the tag pages ([Example](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidity+or+smart-contracts?sort=newest)) to get live updates on new questions.
3. **Setup a good but short list of Interesting and Ignored tags.** For example set [web3js](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web3js), [solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidity) and [evm](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evm) as interesting tags. This will help you see questions, which you can answer, quicker.
4. **Avoid Wall of Text questions.** They take way too much effort for little reward. And usually are syntax errors or bad structure.
5. **Post an answer even though the question has 1–2 or even 3 answers.** In these cases, take your time and answer well. This will usually net you a good sum of rep.
6. **Learn when to edit.** Post a short answer at first and then edit. You have <5 minutes to make that answer shine.
7. **Be humble, thorough and fair.** There are a lot of smart people out there and many will know much more than you about the subject. Be thorough in the code you post, check it for syntax errors and make sure it fits the question. And if you see that the correct answer is already there, upvote it, that person deserves the rep.

Did I miss anything? Who's next? ;-)

Comment: Does @BokkyPooBah get notified?  Congratulations @BokkyPooBah!

Comment: Thanks All. It's has been a good learning experience joining this ESE - having to research that little bit more to justify my answers. And thanks all for pointing out where my answers are a little (or not so little) bit out - keeps me on the straight and narrow.

Comment: @eth no. he has discover it for himself. :-)

Comment: OK, this is not a great event, but passing 2k is the only good thing that happened to me since our black friday, so I permit myself to congratulate. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know, who's next!

@PéterSzilágyi just reached 3k reputation. Congratulations!

Comment: That was my guess too...  Unless we reach out to him, he might not find this meta channel though... ;)

Answer (score 6):

*Someone* just gave me the push I needed to reach 2k. Thank you to whoever that was. This has been a fun/exciting Monday. :D

Comment: Congrats and enjoy the 2k club!

Answer (score 5):

Here we go, @BokkyPooBah already at 3k! Congratulations, now we have 5 users at 3000 reputation!

Answer (score 5):

You guys are on fire!

@NikhilM just reached 2000, too! Congratulations!

Answer (score 3):

Congratualations @eth for being the first to reach 10,000 reputation! Hurray!